# My website isn't loading in Firefox (regular window) or Safari (regular and private windows)

Tags: firefox, safari, webserver, firewall

As the title states, my website is not loading in all browsers. It works just fine in all Chromium browsers, regardless of the settings, and it also works in Firefox in an in-private window. It doesn't work on Firefox regular windows or on Safari in any configuration. It does however work fine on any browser when I run it using npm start on my own PC.

Now, when I say "not work", what I mean is that when you search for the url, the site doesn't load. It  will be spinning for nearly an eternity when it will redirect to a page that says "The connection has timed out. The server is taking too long to respond".

It's a very simple site and the code shouldn't be causing any problems. I'm using React and Bootstrap, and I'm hosting it on a Debian server with Apache using a cloud provider. Based on the error message, I would imagine it is something to do with the server configuration or firewall, but I'm at a loss as to what specific thing it could be. The URL is https://jaylowry.com

So far I have tried looking at the dev tools console to check for errors, but there aren't any appearing. It looks like it just can't contact the server.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: I tested on Mac, PC, Firefox (regular and private), Chrome(regular and incognito) Android and iOS -- All work ..  Next question.  Are  you trying to access this website from inside the same network that the domain lives on?  Meaning is the domain pointed to something like a home computer or home network? -- If it's hosted on a real host -- I suggest clearing all caches, including your DNS cache ..

Comment: Really? That's great to hear! I'm not within the same network, as I'm hosing it on a cloud provider. I might look at my own networks settings though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem continued, and after searching for some time I figured out that some web browsers (seemingly at least Firefox in normal mode and Safari) default to using an http request when accessing a non-specified website for the first time (such as the URL jaylowry.com, without anything before it), and I had blocked port 80 on my firewall settings. I resolved the issue by opening up the firewall and implementing HSTS.